# jquery clone() with deep copy affecting draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application where a button is clicked and a cloned copy of a DOM element is created and placed in a specific location on the page.  This cloned copy needs to be a deep copy because there are events contained in it's children elements.  Therefore the code to create the clone is:

```
var $cloneTags = $div.clone(true, true).attr('id', obj + num);
```

However, when adding `true, true` this has the effect of messing up the draggable functionality of the cloned object (this happens only with the second clone and any subsequent ones). If I get rid of `true, true`, this line of code does what it should and the subsequent objects are draggable:

```
 $cloneTags.draggable({ cursor: "move", snap: '#dropHere', helper: "clone" });
```

However this has the effect of the children element's event handlers no longer work.

My question is how can I create a deep copy but still have each cloned element be individually draggable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to make sure all the events in the children are managed by *"event delegation"* and not binding directly to the elements themselves.

Then you can use a shallow clone and not run into conflicts

Instead of doing:

```
$('.my-draggable-item .someChild').click(function(){...})
```

Do

```
$('#mainContainer').on('click', '.my-draggable-item .someChild', function(){...})
```